# Why does the code executes differently once I introduce else-statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I was doing exercises at [CodingBat](https://codingbat.com/prob/p119308) today and came across an interesting problem:

> Given an array of ints, return True if the array contains a 2 next to a 2 somewhere.

This code runs wrong half times:

```
for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
        print(True)
    else: 
        print(False)
```

for the input `nums = [1, 2, 2]` it gives the output: `False`

And this code gives `True`:

```
for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
        print (True)

print (False)
```

My question is why does the introduction of else statement changes the way the code works?

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of the code.

Comment: And of course make sure that the indentation is correct in the shown code (the scope of the `print (False)` in the second snippet is unclear).

Comment: What is the code attempting to do? What is "wrong"? What is "correct"? What is the expected and actual output? Please add these details to your question.

Comment: Sorry guys. I've just edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving half outputs, as your first code prints `False` and then `True`. This is because you are printing on each iteration. So the first iteration checks whether `1 == 2` and `False` is printed. The next iteration checks if `2 == 2` so `True` is printed.

What you should do, is only print `True` if the condition is found and `break` from the loop, and print `False` only if the loop was exhausted without breaking. This means no consecutive numbers found and can be done with an `else` clause on the for loop:

```py
nums = [1, 2, 2]
for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
        print(True)
        break
else:
    print(False)
```

As to your question:

> why does the introduction of else statement changes the way code works?

Well this is because it is equivalent to adding another condition. For example, this program:

```py
x = 5
if x > 7:
    print("BIG!")
else:
    print("small...")
```

is equivalent to:

```py
x = 5
if x > 7:
    print("BIG!")
if x <= 7:
    print("small...")
```

So by adding this second condition you are giving the code an alternative way of action in case the first one fails. If you omit the `else` (the second condition), the code has no alternative and simply does....nothing

For example, in the two pieces of code above, `small...` will be printed. But in this code:

```py
x = 5
if x > 7:
    print("BIG!")
```

Nothing will be printed at all!

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand the logic.